# Assigning group ID to different number of rows each time in R

Tags: r, data-management

I have some data where a different number of rows corresponds to one ID (e.g. person). Here is what that looks like:

```
label      | response
-----------+------------
'consent'  |  'yes'
'age'      |  '34'
'gender'   |  'female'
'language' |  'english'
'education'|  'college'
'consent'  |  'yes'
'age '     |  '37'
'gender '  |  'male'
'language' |  'english'
'education'|  'high school'
'race'     |  'white'
```

These responses correspond to two people, one who included a response on race while the other didn't. Since everyone has an answer to `consent`, I was wondering if there was a way to assign person ID conditional on the consent label. E.g. if label=consent, assign same ID for every row until next consent. For example, I would want the data to look like this:

```
label      | response   |  ID
-----------+------------+------
'consent'  |  'yes'     |  1 
'age'      |  '34'      |  1
'gender'   |  'female'  |  1
'language' |  'english' |  1
'education'|  'college' |  1
'consent'  |  'yes'     |  2
'age '     |  '37'      |  2
'gender '  |  'male'    |  2
'language' |  'english' |  2
'education'|  'HS'      |  2
'race'     |  'white'   |  2
```

I've tried a number of for loops and if statements, but haven't figured out a way to do it. Hopefully it's possible to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ID = cumsum(label == 'consent'))
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   label     response       ID
   <chr>     <chr>       <int>
 1 consent   yes             1
 2 age       34              1
 3 gender    female          1
 4 language  english         1
 5 education college         1
 6 consent   yes             2
 7 age       37              2
 8 gender    male            2
 9 language  english         2
10 education high school     2
11 race      white           2
```

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you so much!